# Export events data from database with faster rate

Tags: database, time-series, export

I am bit confused in picking database for events data, I am receiving events data with sufficient rate, I am already using Elasticsearch to show analytics but I am facing issue in exporting data, it is taking to much time and some time making CPU high.

Query field that I am using for data  export is ClientID, event_name, timestamp.

Can you suggest some database that will export data in csv with faster rate?, export data size could be up to 100 million